# What is "meal penalty"

Tags: word-meaning

I read a blog and was written as follows.

> "I came to the realization today that every time we decide to agree
>   to waive **meal penalty**, we are actually setting the precedent to have
>   the right to have a meal penalty taken away the next time we negotiate
>   contracts. "

What is "meal penalty"?

For more context, the sentence after it is: "Take advantage of the hard earned rights your union brothers and sisters have fought so hard to earn."

Comment: Good Question! Would you mind linking the blog, if possible, for more context?

Comment: I think this term is Googlable

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In some jurisdictions, and under some collective bargaining agreements, an employer who does not provide an employee sufficient or correctly timed meal breaks must pay the employee a 'meal penalty'.

Under some circumstances the employee may waive this penalty; [here](https://www.replicon.com/help/setting-up-meal-break-enforcement-and-waivers), for instance, is a web page describing how breaks and waivers may be handled in a particular timesheet program.

The author appears to believe that his brothers and sisters should not waive the penalty because it creates pressure on others to do likewise, and even to permit the penalty to be removed under a subsequent contract.